# Android: best way for user to choose from 100s of options

Tags: gui-design, android, spinner

I have an android app that needs some UI improvement. The user has to choose a name from a spinner (dropdown), which initially only had about 20 elements. This was fine, but now the spinner has over 200 names in it, so scrolling down is pretty annoying...
What is a good example of providing a user this many options?

Comment: Hi Simonw, welcome to UX.se! Can you provide some more details regarding the content here? What are the names? What is the app for? etc.